# Prototype hide/show

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs, show-hide

I am a Javascript/jQuery/Prototype newcomer and I have a page that has a Prototype function to get info from a database and put it into some input fields. This was made before I came to work on this site and now I've been asked to add a hide/show div function.

I tried it in jQuery and there were clashes with the two frameworks, (as found in my previous question).

My question now is, how would I go about building a [show/hide](http://jsfiddle.net/qGYVr/3/) function in Prototype? I think it will be easier to do it this way than to re-build the info grabber.

The page I want to add this to is [here](http://www.euroworker.no/user/checkout/). (the green "ny kunde" button should show the div directly but one below it `newCustomer`.

I found this resource: [Hide show div with Prototype](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3411) but I have no idea on how to implement it.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery by following [these instructions](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) to stop from clashing with other libraries.

Prototype provides the Element.hide() and Element.show() methods which means you can hide a div with ID `#hello` with:

```
$('hello').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked absolutely perfectly!